# Access a elements "computed style" in directive

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-directives

I made a directive for this loader thing. I want to do something like below but all styles are undefined. Is there a way to access the "computed styles" of the element in the directive?

```
export const ElementLoader = {
  componentUpdated(el, binding) {
    if (binding.value.isLoading) {
      if (el.style.position !== '' || el.style.position !== 'static') {
        el.style.position = 'relative'
      }

      el.classList.add('is-loading')
    } else {
      el.classList.remove('is-loading')
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: so add `window.getComputedStyle(el)` ?? or whatever vue uses for a global for window

Comment: `element.style` returns styles defined inside inline style attribute, for computed styles you need to use `window.getComputedStyle`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vue.js doesn't provide anything out of the box for this. You must use core [JavaScript API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) for this:

```
componentUpdated(el, binding) {
    const styleObj = window.getComputedStyle(el);
    // Other code...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need it in a directive style well this is not the solution, but you can always v-bind a property dynamically in this case a CSS Class.

[See: Class and style bindings](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Binding-HTML-Classes)

Comment: Is there a reason why it's not good? I need to check current style before I could add a class. Also this is a loader that is gone be general for all elements.

Comment: No, no reason at all, just the directive style is not natively implemented in Vue. You can always go for the custom route, anytime.

Comment: Ok, yea I thought about it and there was really no other way that I could think of to do this. I need to check what style it has and then act upon that. It also has be be a general solution for basically all components/elements. Thanks for the reply Luis :)

Comment: Anytime. Glad to help in any way.